# Script for creating marzipano scenes

Tags: python, windows, loops, imagemagick

Here is the script after being compled, thanks for the people that helped.

The code was made in python 2 and it needs python 2 to be installed in order to run.

you also need imagemagick so the software is able to get the levels done.

you can change the folders, but it basically takes 6 cubefotos from a 360 shot from C:\360\images_folder\project_name\cubefotos*.jpg <-- every file with this format.

**if your pc can't run the code due the ram and cpu used try replaceing every "subprocess.Popen" with "subprocess.call" <- without quotes**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Importing libraries
import os, sys
import glob
import subprocess
import shutil
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
from time import gmtime, strftime

#store and print starting time.
hi =  datetime.now()
print " starting time: " + str(hi) + "\n"

project = 'name of your project'
print 'C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles'
try:
    shutil.rmtree('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles')
except:
    os.makedirs('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles')


#Creation of a list of every file in the directory 
data = glob.glob('C:\\360\\images_folder\\'+project+'\\cubefotos\\*.jpg')


#Set the numbers of folders to be created
le = len(data)
llen = le // 6

#list of faces
innf = ['b', 'd', 'f', 'l', 'r', 'u']

#Start creating folders and subfolders

#First loop: "Global loop" creates root folder for the total "scene" necessary
for i in range(0, llen):
    os.makedirs('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\' + str(i))
    #Second loop: creates levels for the scenes
    for l in range(1, 4):

        os.makedirs(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles', str(i), str(l)))

        #Thrid loop: creates faces subfolders
        for e in innf:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles', str(i), str(l), str(e)))

            #Conditionals: Creates necessary subfolders for each level
            #Level one condition
            if l == 1:
                os.makedirs(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles', str(i), str(l), str(e), str(0)))
            #Level two condition
            elif l == 2:
                for f in range(0, 2):
                    os.makedirs(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles', str(i), str(l) ,str(e), str(f)))

            #Level three condition
            elif l == 3:
                for d in range(0, 4):
                    os.makedirs(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles', str(i), str(l), str(e), str(d)))

#Prints time it took to create folder structure
subprocess.Popen("echo Folders were created in:  " + str(datetime.now() - hi), shell=True)
archivo = 0
temp=0
for i in range(0, llen):
    print "······FOLDER······: " + str(i)
    temp=i*6
    #archivo=0
    #Second loop: creates levels for the scenes
    for l in range(1, 4):
        subprocess.Popen("echo level " + str(l), shell=True)
        #Create and organize images for level 1
        for it in range(0, 6):
            varin = data[i+it]
            v2 = varin[0: 42]
            archivo = it+temp
            #print file
            subprocess.Popen("echo file number: ", shell=True)



            subprocess.Popen("echo face " + str(it), shell=True)
            if int(it) == 0:
                face ='f'
            elif int(it) == 1:
                face ='r'
            elif int(it) == 2:
                face ='b'
            elif int(it) == 3:
                face ='l'
            elif int(it) == 4:
                face ='u'
            elif int(it) == 5:
                face ='d'


            #Normalized paths
                #level 1
            l1 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '1', face, '0', '0.jpg') )
                #level 2
            l20 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '2', face, '0', '0.jpg') )
            l21 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '2', face, '0', '1.jpg') )
            l22 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '2', face, '1', '0.jpg') )
            l23 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '2', face, '1', '1.jpg') )
                #level 3
            l300 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '0', '0.jpg') )
            l301 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '0', '1.jpg') )
            l302 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '0', '2.jpg') )
            l303 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '0', '3.jpg') )
            l310 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '1', '0.jpg') )
            l311 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '1', '1.jpg') )
            l312 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '1', '2.jpg') )
            l313 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '1', '3.jpg') )
            l320 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '2', '0.jpg') )
            l321 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '2', '1.jpg') )
            l322 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '2', '2.jpg') )
            l323 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '2', '3.jpg') )
            l330 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '3', '0.jpg') )
            l331 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '3', '1.jpg') )
            l332 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '3', '2.jpg') )
            l333 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\360\\testing\\'+project+'\\tiles\\', str(i), '3', face, '3', '3.jpg') )


            #check faces for their individual processing requirements

            if it == 4:
                #level 1
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 25%% -rotate 180 " + str(l1) , shell=True)

                #level2
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 50%% -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+0+0 " + str(l20) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 50%% -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+512+0 " + str(l21) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 50%% -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+0+512 " + str(l22) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 50%% -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+512+512 " + str(l23) , shell=True)

                #level3
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+0+0 " + str(l300) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+512+0 " + str(l301) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1024+0 " + str(l302) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1536+0 " + str(l303) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+0+512 " + str(l310) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+512+512 " + str(l311) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1024+512 " + str(l312) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1536+512 " + str(l313) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+0+1024 " + str(l320) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+512+1024 " + str(l321) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1024+1024 " + str(l322) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1536+1024 " + str(l323) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+0+1536 " + str(l330) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+512+1536 " + str(l331) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1024+1536 " + str(l332) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1536+1536 " + str(l333) , shell=True)


            if it == 5:
                #level 1
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 25%% -rotate 180 " + str(l1) , shell=True)

                #level2
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 50%% -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+0+0 " + str(l20) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 50%% -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+512+0 " + str(l21) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 50%% -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+0+512 " + str(l22) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 50%% -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+512+512 " + str(l23) , shell=True)

                #level3
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+0+0 " + str(l300) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+512+0 " + str(l301) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1024+0 " + str(l302) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1536+0 " + str(l303) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+0+512 " + str(l310) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+512+512 " + str(l311) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1024+512 " + str(l312) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1536+512 " + str(l313) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+0+1024 " + str(l320) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+512+1024 " + str(l321) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1024+1024 " + str(l322) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1536+1024 " + str(l323) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+0+1536 " + str(l330) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+512+1536 " + str(l331) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1024+1536 " + str(l332) , shell=True)
                subprocess.call("convert " + data[archivo] + " -rotate 180 -crop 512x512+1536+1536 " + str(l333) , shell=True)


                #print time it takes to process each scene
                subprocess.Popen("echo " + str(datetime.now() - hi), shell=True)

            if it != 4 and it != 5:
                #level 1
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 25%% " + str(l1) , shell=True)

                #level 2
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 50%% -crop 512x512+0+0 " + str(l20) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 50%% -crop 512x512+512+0 " + str(l21) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 50%% -crop 512x512+0+512 " + str(l22) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -resize 50%% -crop 512x512+512+512 " + str(l23) , shell=True)

                #leve 3
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+0+0 " + str(l300) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+512+0 " + str(l301) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+1024+0 " + str(l302) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+1536+0 " + str(l303) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+0+512 " + str(l310) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+512+512 " + str(l311) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+1024+512 " + str(l312) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+1536+512 " + str(l313) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+0+1024 " + str(l320) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+512+1024 " + str(l321) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+1024+1024 " + str(l322) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+1536+1024 " + str(l323) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+0+1536 " + str(l330) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+512+1536 " + str(l331) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+1024+1536 " + str(l332) , shell=True)
                subprocess.Popen("convert " + data[archivo] + " -crop 512x512+1536+1536 " + str(l333) , shell=True)



#prints time it took the process to finish
print "\n"+ "process finished in: " +str(datetime.now() - hi)
```

Comment: On the command-line, `python text-file-name`.  It is a convention to give python source code filenames the extension `.py` (not `.txt`).

Comment: What does it mean? I understand that you are talking me about calling the .py in the cmd right?

Comment: Don't add slashes to parameters in `os.path.join`, e.g. use `os.path.join('C:/360/Pruebas/tiles', str(i), str(l), str(e))`. Also, the integer division operator is `//`, e.g. `llen = le // 6`.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on just what you are asking:

subprocess help pages: [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html)

In python 2.7, you want to make your call:

```
subprocess.Popen([application_path, arg1, arg2, ...])
```

If however you are using python 3, then you should then be using `run` instead of `Popen`:

```
subprocess.run([application_path, arg1, arg2, ...])
```

Comment: So I changed last line to: `subprocess.Popen(['C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.4-Q16/convert.exe', str(it), '-resize 50%', 'C:/360/tiles/'+ str(i) + '/1/'+ face +'/0/0.jpg'])` But it is showing in the cmd that the command like is being printed with '' example: Error '-resize 50%' not recognized

Comment: @Thriskel, `'-resize'` and `'50%'` are separate parameters. You're thinking of them as a conceptual unit instead of how a machine will parse them. convert.exe sees a single `-resize 50%` argument that it doesn't understand. Also you can't depend on programs understanding paths that use forward slashes in a command line. You need to normalize the path, e.g. `os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:/360/tiles', str(i), '1', face, '0', '0.jpg'))`.

Comment: It fails to complete the action but if I manually type the same input my script gave it, it Works. Is there something I am missing in that line that doesn't let the software to correctly execute?